# Output of cornerHarris() in OpenCV using an swift wrapper is just colored noise

Tags: c++, swift, opencv

I'm doing an iOS project using OpenCV to take images from the camera and run Harris corner detection on them. I'm converting from UIImage to Mat to then run the cornerHarris openCV function.

```
#import <opencv2/opencv.hpp>
#import "OpenCVWrapper.h"
#import <opencv2/imgcodecs/ios.h>

using namespace std;

@implementation OpenCVWrapper

- (UIImage *) detectCornersIn:(UIImage *)anImage {

// Convert image to Mat and to grayscale
cv::Mat imgMat, imgMatGray, imgMatDst;
UIImageToMat(anImage, imgMat);
cv::cvtColor(imgMat, imgMatGray, CV_BGR2GRAY);

// Perform Harris Corner Detection
imgMatDst.zeros(imgMatGray.size(), CV_32FC1);
cornerHarris(imgMatGray, imgMatDst, 2, 3, 0.04);

return MatToUIImage(imgMatDst);
}

@end
```

All the inputs seem to have the right properties, but the output image from the function seems to be just random noise (below):
[conerHarris output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K7SqB.jpg)

Any idea what I'm doing wrong? Thanks.

Comment: What is the input image being used? Can you upload that as well?

Comment: The input is from the camera on the iOS device. the output is roughly the same with all the inputs I've given it.